# Why does myObj[`${this.isTrueOrFalse? 'a' : 'b'}`] give undefined?

Tags: javascript

In my Angular project, I want to conditionally set properties of an object like so:

```
myObj[`${isTrueOrFalse? 'a' : 'b'}`]['someProperty'] = someValue
```

But this gives undefined. Why is this happening? Any ideas?

Example:

```
this.addNewRequestData[`${this.isAzureBoard ? 'azure' : 'jira'}`]['someproperty'] = someValue;
```

This code gives error that cannot set property 'someproperty' of undefined.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Does the object already have an `a` or `b` property? You can't create a nested property in a property that doesn't exist.

Comment: share your object,

Comment: @Barmar: I have already created objects for both properties

Comment: The example isn't any better than the original code. You need to show the original value of the object.

Comment: There's no need for the template literal, you can just use the conditional expression by itself.

Comment: That error message means that either `azure` or `jira` properties don't exist.

Comment: @Barmar: I tried it without template literal also, same error.

Comment: I didn't say it was causing the problem, I just said it's unnecessary. They're equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should initialize you object first.
Like this.

```
var myObj = {a : {}, b: {}};
```

See the below code.

```js
var isTrueOrFalse = true;
var myObj = {a : {}, b: {}};
myObj[isTrueOrFalse ? 'a' : 'b']['someProperty'] = 'somevalue';
console.log(myObj);
```

Comment: Strange!! I tried the same in my project, i am still getting error.

Comment: have you declare you variable like this? : addNewRequestData = {jira: {}, azure: {}}

Comment: Yes, i did. It seems to be another function that is causing the issue.

Comment: You can add that function in your question i can try to solve that. And if you satisfied my above answer than please upvote and approve the answer. Thanks,

Comment: Template literals are not required here. Just ternary is enough.